# trying to get started with flyway on redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, flyway

I am trying to get started with flyway (for Redshift) and go through the commandline tutorial

[flyway commandline tutorial](https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/firststeps/commandline)

Unfortunately, whatever command I issue, like "flyway baseline" or "flyway migrate" (I created a simple create table script in the sql folder) results in the same error message:

ERROR: Unknown prefix for location (should be either filesystem: or classpath:): D:\Software\flyway-5.1.4\sql

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `filesystem:` prefix in the `locations` argument like this:

```
flyway -locations=filesystem:D:/Software/flyway-5.1.4/sql ...
```

Comment: I had the entry but missed the "filesystem:" part
Thanks

Comment: @EricMamet cool, do you want to accept / upvote the answer in that case?

Comment: New to stack overflow... More than happy to accept as answer. Just need to find the right button!

I voted but it's not counted as I have less than 15 reputation points...